# Generate tree path with write permission

Tags: linux, windows, display, file-permissions

I need to know what folder I can read and what I can write into. But the file system is huge, so I can't test it one by one or just generate a huge list with a script. I need to have a kind of directory tree, like in `explorer.exe` or `dolphin`. But that only shows folder depending on the filter, whether it be write access or read access

Do you know how can I achieve that on Linux or Windows?

Any alternative ideas welcome

Comment: What kind of file system is it? Linux and Windows do file permissions very differently. On windows, you could try a (free) tool like this that takes stuff like group memberships into account automatically: https://www.netwrix.com/netwrix_effective_permissions_reporting_tool.html

Comment: On ext4 or NTFS. Even other filesystem if necessary, I can move the files or mount them to get that tree files

Comment: Does the Netwrix tool do what you're looking for? Are you only looking for folders that your current user account has access to?

Answer (score 0):

Linux example using:

- `find` and `sudo -u USERNAME test -w` to check for write permissions,
- `2>/dev/null` to hide access denied messages
- then using `sed` to generate a tree view:

```
# spaced tree view
[user@linux ~]$ find /home/ -type d 2>/dev/null -exec sudo -u USERNAME test -w '{}' \; -print | sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//  /g' -e 's/^//'
  USERNAME
    dir1
      dir11
    dir2
      dir22

# or with dashes
[user@linux ~]$ find /home/ -type d 2>/dev/null -exec sudo -u USERNAME test -w '{}' \; -print | sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/'
 |-USERNAME
 |---dir1
 |-----dir11
 |---dir2
 |-----dir22
```

To check for "read" access instead, use `test -r`. To limit to a certain folder depth, use `find / -maxdepth 3`. To check and include files in the output, remove `-type d`

`sudo -u USERNAME` can be excluded if you are checking access for your current user